# Why does an empty child element with display: inline-block create space in its parent element?

Tags: css, block, display

Here is a parent element which has a child, the parent element does not have any width or height property
but the child has 100% percent width and height and display: inline-block .

HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .parent {
        background-color: red;

      }
      .child {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">Hello
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't expect the child to take any space because  it is empty and the parent does not have width and height but it makes a empty space in the parent .

[image]

I can use display block to fix this but i just want to know why this happens when display inline-block is used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent element has a line-height. By giving the child element 100% width, you're guaranteeing that it will be on line on its own. Because it's empty, it has 0 height (the 100% height has no effect because the parent element does not have a definite height), but the line in which it resides has the height of the parent's line-height. So the parent has the height of two lines.

Comment: So why when display block is used on child , it does not happen?

Comment: @radman Because `display:block` elements are not in a line, like `display:inline-block` elements are. So there is no second line for the parent's line-height to be applied to. The `display:block` element makes it's own vertical space instead, but since it's empty, that vertical space is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an empty block using the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.child:not(:empty) {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  /*  this is really need? */
  /* height: 100%; */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">Hello
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because all child elements without specifying sizes have by default the maximum proportional sizes of their parents.

For example, if you have a div with another div in it, let's call them div1 and div2.

div2 without explicitly specified size parameters will take the dimensions of div1,

In your case parent receives the size of the body in proportion to the sizes of the two elements "Hello" and Child
to put it simply, without explicitly specified size parameters width = 100%, and height is counted from child elements

Answer (score -1):

The child element is moved to a new line because it has `width: 100%`. Because of this, it does not fit on the same line with the word `Hello`. You can verify this by slightly reducing the **width** of the child element.